# Libgdx Scene2D Table background image not showing up

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I am using Libgdx's Scene2D API to build by UI and everything has been working as expected until now. I created a `Skin` and a `TextureAtlas` and linked them as so:

```
Skin skin = new Skin();
TextureAtlas uiElements1 = new TextureAtlas("skins/uielements1.txt");
skin.addRegions(uiElements1);
skin.load(Gdx.files.internal("skins/uiskin.json"));
```

And then I tried to create a `Table`:

```
Table table = new Table(skin);
table.setWidth(stage.getWidth());
table.align(Align.center|Align.top);
table.setPosition(0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
table.padTop(30);
table.setBackground("grey_button02");
```

And Finally I added a `Label` to the `Table`:

```
Label gameTitle = new Label("Nameless Project", skin, "title");
table.add(gameTitle).padBottom(10).row();
```

Once I added the `Table` to my `Stage`, only the elements in it would show up and not the background image. I tried using `background(String s)`, `setBackground(String s)`, `background(Drawable d)`, and `setBackground(Drawable d)`. None of those 4 methods seemed to work for me.

I also tried calling `pack()` and `setFillParent(true)` but both of those made my table disappear. I have gone through just about every Google result and I can't find anyone else with my issue.

**EDIT**

Here is my uiskin.json file

```
{
  com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: fonts/FutureThin.fnt } },
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
   default: { down: blue_button03, up: blue_button04, font: default-font },
  },
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
    default:  {
      titleFont: default-font
     }
   },
   com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
    title: {
        font: default-font
     }
   }
}
```

And the entire class rendering the stage:

```
public class MainMenu implements Screen {

    GameClass myGame;

    Stage stage;
    Skin skin;

    Table table;
    TextButton singlePlayer;
    TextButton multiPlayer;
    Label gameTitle;


    public MainMenu(GameClass g) {
        myGame = g;

        // Create Skin, load texture Atlas, load skin
        skin = new Skin();
        TextureAtlas uiElements1 = new TextureAtlas("skins/uielements1.txt");
        skin.addRegions(uiElements1);
        skin.load(Gdx.files.internal("skins/uiskin.json"));

        // Create stage
        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());

        // Create Table
        table = new Table(skin);
        table.setWidth(stage.getWidth());
        table.align(Align.center|Align.top);
        table.setPosition(0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        table.padTop(30);
        table.setBackground("grey_button02");

        // Game Title
        gameTitle = new Label("Nameless Project", skin, "title");
        table.add(gameTitle).padBottom(30).row();

        // Single Player button
        singlePlayer = new TextButton("Single Player", skin, "default");
        singlePlayer.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent e, float x, float y) {
                myGame.setScreen(new WorldTesting(myGame));
            }
        });
        table.add(singlePlayer).width(300).padBottom(30).row();

        // Multiplayer Button
        multiPlayer = new TextButton("Multiplayer", skin, "default");
        multiPlayer.setWidth(350);
        multiPlayer.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent e, float x, float y) {
                // Change Scenes
            }
        });
        table.add(multiPlayer).width(300).padBottom(30).row();

        stage.addActor(table);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    public void show() {

    }

    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }

    public void hide(){

    }
    public void resize(int x, int y) {

    }
    public void pause() {

    }
    public void resume() {

    }
    public void dispose() {

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the skin file content ?

Comment: Can you show us the class that renders the Stage?

Comment: @WutipongWongsakuldej, I added both the requested files

Comment: My bad, I should have ask the atlas file instead. The file `"skins/uielements1.txt"` should contains a drawable name `grey_button02`.

Comment: It does, I have used the atlas elsewhere. And when I change the name to a texture that isn't in the atlas I get an error

Comment: Try adding stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true); in your resize method.

Comment: That didn't work. Everything shows up except for the table background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the fix. You need to call `table.pack()` before the background will show up. I was calling `table.pack()` but positioning the table offscreen after the pack so I assumed the `pack()` made it disappear.